# loop for image processing in python / attribute error 'NoneType'

Tags: python, opencv

I have almost 900 .jpg images (obtained by splitting a video in frames, each image is 116ko), and I want to compare each of my frames to the first one (= frame0) using the "Mean Squared Error".

It is quite easy to load two images and compare them, but it is much more difficult (for me at least) to write a loop that loads and compares my images.
My aim is just to have a list with all the "Mean Squared Error" (MSE) values in it.

**Issues:**

I don't need to have all the images loaded or opened at the same time, but I don't know how to load an image just during the processing time.

My images are in the same folder as my `.py` file.

When I run my code, it returns:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Susie\Documents\programmes_python\python\images_video\comparaison-images2.py", line 46, in 
>       compare_images(frame0, frame0)
>     File "C:\Users\Susie\Documents\programmes_python\python\images_video\comparaison-images2.py", line 24, in compare_images
>       s = ssim(imageA, imageB)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\skimage\measure_structural_similarity.py", line 151, in compare_ssim
>       "win_size exceeds image extent.  If the input is a multichannel "
>   ValueError: win_size exceeds image extent.  If the input is a multichannel (color) image, set multichannel=True.

```
# import the necessary packages
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim as ssim
import numpy as np
import cv2
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def mse(imageA, imageB):
    # the 'Mean Squared Error' between the two images is the
    # sum of the squared difference between the two images
    err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2)
    err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])

    # return the MSE, the lower the error, the more "similar"
    # the two images are
    return err

def compare_images(imageA, imageB):
    # compute the mean squared error and structural similarity
    # index for the images
    m = mse(imageA, imageB)
    s = ssim(imageA, imageB)
    mse_list.append(m)
    ssim_list.append(s)
    print (mse_list)
    print (ssim_list)


# load the images and convert the images to grayscale
frame0 = cv2.imread("frame0.jpg")

mypath='C:\Users\Susie\Documents\programmes_python\python\images_video'
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]
images = np.empty(len(onlyfiles), dtype=object)

for n in range(1, len(onlyfiles)):
  images[n] = cv2.imread( join(mypath,onlyfiles[n]) )
  images[n] = cv2.cvtColor(images[n], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# compare the images
mse_list = []
ssim_list = []
compare_images(frame0, frame0)

for n in range(1, len(onlyfiles)):
    compare_images(frame0, images[n])
```

Comment: You should put the complete stacktrace so people know at least which line is failing. The error is most probably an image that did not load correctly (maybe it does not exist) and imread returns none, then you try to use it and it gives you error.

Comment: change your path to : `mypath='C:/Users/Susie/Documents/programmes_python/python/images_video'`

Comment: thank you, it seems that none of my images were found. I change the location of my .py file (save it in the same file than the images) and now it does'nt return me the attribute error.

Comment: @JeruLuke it returns me the same attribute error with this new path.

Comment: @SusieB if your `.py` is in the same location as the images then it shouldn't be a problem as you said. By the way where is `frame0.jpg` located? Ensure that as well.

Comment: @JeruLuke Yes that way it work thaks ! Now it seems that i have a trouble with my type of input (see the edit). It is weird because when I load the image like this it works fine :     `# load the images 
frame0 = cv2.imread("frame0.jpg")
frameX = cv2.imread("frame20.jpg")

 
# convert the images to grayscale
frame0 = cv2.cvtColor(frame0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
frameX = cv2.cvtColor(frameX, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: I think in line `compare_images(frame0, images[n])` you are comparing a *grayscale image* with a *3-channel image*. **Quick fix:** just change this `frame0 = cv2.imread("frame0.jpg")` to `frame0 = cv2.imread("frame0.jpg", 0)`

Comment: @JeruLuke `frame0.jpg` is in the same folder than the rest of the images and my .py file

Comment: @JeruLuke yes you're right, I forgot to convert my `frame0.jpg` in grayscale

Comment: @JeruLuke my last error was forgetting a 'p' in my append module. Now my code works, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to mention a couple of programming mistakes:

**1. Attribute error :**

Ensure that the `.py` file and the collection of images are present within the same folder. If they are not, mention the path exclusively for eg. `mypath='C:/Users/Susie/Documents/programmes_python/python/images_video`

**2. Value error :**

Comparing a *multi-channel* image with a *single channel* image throws this error. Make sure the images are of the same size and have same number of channels.

Making mistakes is a step to learning !!!

Comment: how do I ensure they have same number of channels? I have extracted a bunch of frames from a video... they should have the same or similar properties right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using grayscale images, you need to specify this by adding the 0 parameter as follows:

```
frame0 = cv2.imread("frame0.jpg", 0)
```

Check OpenCV documentation for more detail: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html